# facebook app dev; auto-gen'd heroku prod host; local dev virtual host; tunnlr; FB login-issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing my first Facebook app using custom Open Graph actions and objects, and I'm trying to avoid needing to deploy after each code-change (in this case, to my automatically setup heroku-account).

The problem started while I was getting set up to test the publishing of my first custom action. I was trying to set up everything in terms of the dev-version of my facebook-app, except for my "object" page, which, as I understand it, needs to be publicly accessible (to scrape the OG meta-tags).

I made a test-page for my custom object, copied the auto-generated set of OG meta-tags into it (citing the dev-version of my app_id, but with the public URL of the prod-version of my app for og:url)  Then, I used the facebook "lint" tool on that test-page, and it, I guess not surprisingly, complained about that public domain being invalid for the relevant app (the dev-version of my facebook app).

```
Object Base Domain Not Allowed: Object at URL 
'http://foo.herokuapp.com/testEventPage.php' of type 'foo:product' is 
invalid because the domain 'foo.herokuapp.com' is not allowed 
for the specified application id '(the app_id)'.
```

Then, I learned about using Tunnlr to port-forward from a public site to my local env and proceeded to get that set up.

I'm using MAMP with a virtual host config as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
  DocumentRoot "(the relevant docroot)"
  ServerName foo.local
  SetEnv FACEBOOK_APP_ID (my dev FB app-id)
  SetEnv FACEBOOK_SECRET (my dev FB secret)
</VirtualHost>
```

And I'm using tunnlr, with the cmdln for it pointing to port 8888.

Using the public URL provided by Tunnlr, I am successful in accessing my local pages, but, when I try to use the "Login" button on the page that came with the example PHP-code from Facebook, the login-dialog pops up but immediately disappears, though when accessing it directly locally it works fine.

Could this be cookie-related?  Something to do with port-forwarding and cookies?

Is there a better way to develop Facebook apps, in particular ones involving custom Open Graph actions and objects?

EDIT: like the doctor said, if it hurts when you move your arm like that, don't move your arm like that!  In other words, access the Tunnlr-URL via the Facebook-Canvas URL, which POSTs the embedding page's current login to your own page; and, as a user (optionally a test-user), don't use the example-code's login-button; instead use the embedding page's login-feature.  So, I've answered my own question.